# EAS BUILD fails on EXPO sdk47 and sdk48

Tags: react-native, expo

Locally works fine, but when I try the build on a managed EXPO project on android it fails on Gradle as in the picture bellow:
[image: android error]

On SDK46 it builds fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the wrong version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. You need 1.5.20 or higher but `expo-app-auth` uses 1.4.21.

`expo-app-auth` [is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-app-auth) so you should migrate to [`expo-auth-session`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/) and that should fix this.

You could try specifying the Kotlin version with [`expo-build-properties`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/) like this.

```
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            kotlinVersion: "1.5.20"
          },
```

But I recommend migrating out from the deprecated library.